# django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1074, "Column length too big for column 'value' (max = 16383); use BLOB or TEXT instead")

Tags: python, django

I am trying to host my website using FileZilla and PuTTY. For that, I have added the code in FileZilla remote site and I have created a database named `jobs` using the following commands in the PuTTY app.

```
sudo mysql -u root #For Maria DB
CREATE DATABASE jobs;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON jobs.*TO 'hello'@'localhost';
flush privileges;
exit
```

Then `python3 manage.py makemigrations` command is executed and after that when I executed the `python3 manage.py migrate` command I got an error like this.

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1074, "Column length too big for column 'value' (max = 16383); use BLOB or TEXT instead")
```

models.py

```
class IndividualProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Address_line_1 = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    Address_line_2 = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    postal_code =models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=11, choices=GENDER_SELECT)
    alternate_number = PhoneNumberField(unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    aadhar_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    skills = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    resume = models.FileField(upload_to='resume', blank=True, null=True, validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['pdf'])])
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='individual_profile_pic', validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['jpg','png','jpeg'])])
    academic_qualification = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

Can anyone suggest a solution to solve this issue?

Comment: set a smaller max_lenth for field field ```value``` in your models.py, something like ```max_lenth=255```

Comment: For some fields I have given `max_length` more than 255. I have given up to 5000.Is that the problem@Sumithran

Comment: yeah, that might be the problem. can you share the models.py?

Comment: yes. I have edited my question by adding models.py. Can you go through it.@Sumithran